# Compute and Update vaules if four textboxes are filled VB.net

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I want to compute and update the database if four text boxes are filled.

If 1 or 2 or 3 are filled it will not compute, it will just update to database.

here is my code.

```
 Dim constring As String = "Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\SLACdb.mdb;"
    Dim con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(constring)
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()

    Dim prelim, midterm, prefinal, final, ave, eq As String

    prelim = txtboxprelim.Text
    midterm = txtboxmidterm.Text
    prefinal = txtboxsemi.Text
    final = txtboxfinals.Text
    ave = txtboxave.Text
    eq = txtboxequivalent.Text

    Dim sql As String = "UPDATE StudentLoad SET prelim = ?, midterm = ?, semifinals = ?, finals = ?" & _
                        " WHERE  name = '" & txtboxname.Text & "' "

    If prelim = "" Or midterm = "" Or prefinal = "" Or final = "" Then
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, con)


        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", prelim)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", midterm)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", prefinal)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", final)

        Try
            con.Open()
            If (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery > 0) Then

            End If
            con.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        Me.StudentRemarksTableAdapter.Fill(Me.SLACdbDataSet.StudentRemarks)
    Else
        txtboxave.Text = (prelim + midterm + prefinal + final) / 4
        If txtboxave.Text <= 77 Then
            txtboxequivalent.Text = 3
        ElseIf txtboxave.Text <= 80 Then
            txtboxequivalent.Text = 2.75
        ElseIf txtboxave.Text <= 83 Then
            txtboxequivalent.Text = 2.5
        ElseIf txtboxave.Text <= 86 Then
            txtboxequivalent.Text = 2.25
        ElseIf txtboxave.Text <= 89 Then
            txtboxequivalent.Text = 2
        ElseIf txtboxave.Text <= 92 Then
            txtboxequivalent.Text = 1.75
        ElseIf txtboxave.Text <= 95 Then
            txtboxequivalent.Text = 1.5
        ElseIf txtboxave.Text <= 98 Then
            txtboxequivalent.Text = 1.25
        ElseIf txtboxave.Text <= 100 Then
            txtboxequivalent.Text = 1
        Else
            txtboxequivalent.Text = 5
        End If

        Dim constring1 As String = "Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\SLACdb.mdb;"
        Dim con1 As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(constring1)
        Dim cmd1 As OleDbCommand
        Dim dt1 As DataTable = New DataTable()


        Dim sql1 As String = "UPDATE StudentLoad SET prelim = ?, midterm = ?, semifinals = ?, finals = ?, average = ?, equivalent = ?" & _
                        " WHERE  name = '" & txtboxname.Text & "'"
        cmd1 = New OleDbCommand(sql1, con1)


        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", prelim)
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", midterm)
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", prefinal)
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", final)
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", ave)
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", eq)


        Try
            con1.Open()
            If (cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery > 0) Then

            End If
            con1.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End If
    Me.StudentRemarksTableAdapter.Fill(Me.SLACdbDataSet.StudentRemarks)
    Admin.StudentLoadTableAdapter.Update(SLACdbDataSet.StudentLoad)
```

with this code it only update the database if the four text boxes are filled it doesn't compute.

sorry for bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that the prelim, midterm, prefinal, final, ave and eq are string.

In order for you to compute your average, you need to make those variables as an integer. Thus 
`Dim prelim as integer = convert.toint32(txtboxprelim.text)` and also do that to midterm, prefinal, final, ave and eq. Your `cmd.parameters` should be

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", txtboxprelims.text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", txtboxmidterm.text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", txtboxprefinal.text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", txtboxfinal.text)
```

in your else statement below:

```
txtboxave.Text = (prelim + midterm + prefinal + final) / 4
```

should be

```
ave = (prelim + midterm + prefinal + final) / 4
```

replace your txtboxave.text to ave, then below the if and else statements add:

```
txtboxequivalent.text = eq
txtboxave.text = ave
```

finally, your `cmd.paremeters` below should be:

```
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", prelim.tostring)
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", midterm.tostring)
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", prefinal.tostring)
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", final.tostring)
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", ave.tostring)
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", eq.tostring)
```